# In a finite group, Number of elements satisfying $x^{5}=e$ are multiple of $5$

Tags: group-theory

This is a question from Gallian. I have checked by taking group of addition modul0 10. There are 4 elements satisfying $x^{4}=e$ or order 4, which is not multiple of 5. Am i missing something?

Comment: Is it $x^4$ or $x^5$? For $x^5$, there are $5$ elements satisfying the condition (the even numbers), so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: Well if $x$ satisfies $x^5 = e$, then $x^k$ also does, for we have $(x^k)^5 = (x^5)^k = e^k = e$.

Comment: 0,2,,4,6 and 8 satisfy x$^{5}$=e in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Comment: @HumbleStudent okay i didnot count 0 as i thought it has 0 order because of identity and not 5

Comment: question doesn't say anything about the order. Just asks for elements that possibly satisfy that relation.

Comment: I will try to prove it again then

Comment: @Slade This is in first chapter i think question no 60.....i have 8th edition

Answer (score 2):

Well, I remember seeing a nice proof of Cauchy's theorem by group actions. I just noticed that in fact that proves that for a prime $p$, number of solutions of $x^p = e$ has to be divisible by $p$.

Consider the set $S$ of solutions of $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdots x_p = e$. There is a unique choice for $x_p$ for any chosen $x_1, \ldots, x_{p-1}$. So  $|S|= |G|^{p-1}$, which is divisible by $p$. Consider the action of $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$  on $S$ by translation, i.e., $1 \cdot (x_1 , \cdots , x_p) = (x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_p, x_1)$. By orbit-Stabilizer theorem, the cardinality of the orbits can be either $1$ or $5$. Now orbit is of cardinality $1$ iff $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_p$, in which case it corresponds to a solution for $x^p = e$. Now $|S| = \sum _{\mathcal{O} \text{is an orbt}} \mathcal |\mathcal O|$. Since $p \mid |S|$, number of orbits of size $1$ has to be a multiple of $p$. Therefore, number of solutions of $x^p = e$ is also divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 2):

You get this with almost all proofs of Cauchy. Consider the set $S$ of $p$-tuples $(a_1,a_2\dots a_n)$ such that $a_1a_2\dots a_n=e$.

Notice that in total there are $|G|^{p-1}$ such tuples ( a multiple of $p$) since we can pick $a_1,a_2\dots a_{p-1}$ arbitrarily and force $a_n$ to be the inverse of the product of the first $p-1$.

Now consider the rotations of $a_1,a_2\dots a_p$, they are also in $S$. For each element of $S$ it can have either one or $p$ rotations ( because $p$ is a prime).

Notice there is one rotation if and only if the tuple is $(x,x,\dots x)$ with $x^p=1$.

The number of tuples with $p$ rotations is clearly a multiple of $p$, and since $|S|$ is a multiple of $p$ we must conclude the number of tuples of the form $(x,x,\dots x)$ is also a multiple of $p$, as was desired.